# how to get checked checkbox table row value in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-3

**VIEW PAGE**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll"  name="checkAll" /></th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
        <th>Stipendiary Type</th>
        <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
        <th class="text-right">Stipendiary ₹</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " name="bene_id[]" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="500" tabindex ="-1" />
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jeinbai Nesamony</td>
        <td>Poor Pension</td>
        <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
            <input type="text" name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right wagein">500.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " name="bene_id[]" value="2" /><input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="400" tabindex ="-1" />
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
        <td>Poor Aid</td>
        <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
            <input type="text" name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right wagein">400.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " name="bene_id[]" value="3" /><input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="400" tabindex ="-1" />
        </td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Thasammal Thangaiah</td>
        <td>Poor Aid</td>
        <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
            <input type="text" name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right wagein">400.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " name="bene_id[]" value="4" /><input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="400" tabindex ="-1" />
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Roselet</td>
        <td>Poor Aid</td>
        <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
            <input type="text" name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right wagein">400.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " name="bene_id[]" value="5" /><input type="hidden" name="amount[]" value="400" tabindex ="-1" />
        </td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Kamalam Chellam R.</td>
        <td>Poor Aid</td>
        <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
            <input type="text" name="bonus[]" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
        </td>
        <td class="text-right wagein">400.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

**MY REQUIREMENT**

I want to save bellowed data's to table 
1. bene_id
2. Bonus ₹
3. Stipendiary ₹

I've fetch this table data form existing Beneficiary Table. So Bene_id and Stipendiary ₹ value get from that tabel. Bonus ₹ will be an input.
Now i want to save table data to the payment table.
I'm trying to post the value by array. it's working fine.
now i've an issue with the check box. i want to neglect the row value that unchecked. That means i want row value which was checkbox : checked
i'm expecting jquery for passing checkbox : checked row value to hidden input array.

Comment: if i unchecked row 2 and row 3, do you wish to post the rest of their data ( i mean row 2, 3)

Comment: as a sidenote: id's should be unique!

Comment: yes if i unchecked  row 2 and row 3. i want to post row 1, row 4 and row 5

Comment: Ok, you don't need jquery to post. Use normal html form with action to your action method in specified controller

Comment: "*it's working fine*" ... since you only have form elements for the checkbox and Bonus .., where's the code that you're using to extract the other fields and build the array to post to the back end?

Comment: Using hidden fields to other values will fix it.

Comment: He just need a hidden field to (Stipendiary), because we are going to take advantadge of checkbox value to store bene_id

Comment: He just need a hidden field to (Stipendiary), because we are going to take advantadge of checkbox value to store bene_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i told you in the comments section, you can use normal HTML forms to submit to the action method on your controller, but you need to modify your form a little bit, this is the easiest solution.

Despite of option one simplicity i decided to give you another approach to solve this problem, so first look at the code of HTML and JavaScript:

```
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkAll"  name="checkAll" /></th>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
     <th>Stipendiary Type</th>
     <th class="text-right box">Bonus ₹</th>
     <th class="text-right">Stipendiary ₹</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="details">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " id="bene_id" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Jeinbai Nesamony</td>
    <td>Poor Pension</td>
    <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
    <input type="text" name="bonus" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right wagein" id="amount">500.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " id="bene_id" value="2" />
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Chellammal Kochimoni</td>
    <td>Poor Aid</td>
    <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
        <input type="text" name="bonus" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right wagein" id="amount" >400.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " id="bene_id" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Thasammal Thangaiah</td>
    <td>Poor Aid</td>
    <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
        <input type="text" name="bonus" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right wagein" id="amount" >400.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " id="bene_id" value="4" />
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Roselet</td>
    <td>Poor Aid</td>
    <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
        <input type="text" name="bonus" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right wagein" id="amount">400.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkclass " id="bene_id" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Kamalam Chellam R.</td>
    <td>Poor Aid</td>
    <td class="text-right box" id="hideshow">
        <input type="text" id="bonus" value="" class="tbl-input-cus bonus" tabindex ="1" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right wagein" id="amount">400.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url(assets/js/jquery.min.js) ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function jsonify(){

    var rows = $('#details tr');
    var a = [];
    rows.each(function(){

        if($(this).find('#bene_id').is(':checked'))
        {
           var bene_id       = $(this).find('#bene_id').val();
           var stipendiary   = $(this).find('#amount').html();
           var bonus         = $(this).find('#bonus').val();

           var x = {
                bene_id:bene_id,
                stipendiary:stipendiary,
                bonus:bonus
            };
            a.push(x);
        }
    });
    var c = JSON.stringify(a);
    return c;
}

 $(function(){

   $('#submit').click(function(){
       $data = jsonify();

       $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'<?= base_url('controller/method_name') ?>',
          data:{details:data},
          success:function(response)
          {
            //if you data save successfuly, do sth here..
          }
       });
    });

 });
```

The following code is a PHP code of the action method on the specified controller:

```
   public function method_name()
   {
         $details  = json_decode($this->input->post('details'));

         foreach($details as $det ){

            $bene_id     = $det->bene_id;
            $stipendiary = $det->stipendiary;
            $bonus       = $det->bonus;

            // your logic goes here
         }
   }
```

In this solution i didn't considered the validation and security issues, because i wanted to make it simple, so before you put it in your production server you must deal with these issues.

I hope it helps.